# Understanding 「いいくらいの...」

Tags: particle-の, particle-くらい

In

> 僕は日本一と言っても**いいくらいの**真面目な優等生だよ

I'm trying to understand

1. What いいくらい ("approximately good"?) is doing in the sentence.
2. Whether の is acting as a nominalizer of いいくらい or as a possessive particle.

My current translation attempt is

> As for me, they'll even (も) say I'm Japan's best <いいくらい>...am a serious honor roll student.

I'm tempted to translate it as

> As for me, they'll even (も) say I'm Japan's best and most serious honor roll student.

but this is (i) ignoring いいくらい and (ii) treating の as a possessive particle (which doesn't make sense since 日本一と言っても isn't a noun on the left side of の).

Answer (score 3):

1. You are parsing the sentence in the wrong way. The いい part belongs to 言っても. 日本一と言ってもいい here means "be able to be called the number one in Japan."
2. の is a possessive particle. 日本一と言ってもいいくらい modifies 真面目な優等生. Also, くらい doesn't mean "approximately" but means "to the extent." In this sense, you can replace くらい with ほど if you prefer.

To summarize,

> 僕は日本一と言ってもいいくらいの真面目な優等生だよ
>
> I am a serious top student, top enough to be called the number one in Japan.

Comment: Thanks! If の is the possesive particle here, shouldn't there be another の to nominalize 日本一と言ってもいいくらい (since this phrase isn't a noun, and  AのB requires both A and B to be nouns)? The pattern would be `(<relative clause>の)の(<noun>)`.  **EDIT:** I just realized the particle ~くらい itself could turn relative clauses into noun phrases. I guess that's what's going on here?

Comment: Sorry I am not knowledgeable on nitty-gritty details about grammar but I think the role of くらい can vary depending on how it is used in a sentence. In this case, くらい clearly acts as a noun.